Inter process communication with protobuf-net.grpc (NET48 NET8)
I'm trying to establish interprocess communication between .net framework (4.8) and .net (8) with protobuf-net.grpc.
The communication between client/server in .net 8 works according to the instructions/example project: https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/gettingstarted
When creating a .net framework client, I get the exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: "The channel configuration isn't valid on this operating system. The channel is configured to use WinHttpHandler and the current version of Windows doesn't support HTTP/2 features required by gRPC. Windows Server 2022 or Windows 11 or later is required. For more information, see https://aka.ms/aspnet/grpc/netframework."

According to the instructions, .net framework is also supported.
Tested with .net 8 -> works
Implementation like example on server-side:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.ListenLocalhost(10042, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
            });
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();

Implementation like example on client-side (.net framework):
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    GrpcClientFactory.AllowUnencryptedHttp2 = true;
    using (var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:10042"))
    {
        var calculator = channel.CreateGrpcService<ICalculator>();
        var result = await calculator.MultiplyAsync(new MultiplyRequest { X = 12, Y = 4 });
        Console.WriteLine(result.Result);
    }
}


This is more of a general "gRPC on .NET Framework" question than protobuf-net.Grpc - since protobuf-net.Grpc simply uses the channels provided; however, the requirements for gRPC on .NET Framework are fully specified in the link cited, https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/grpc/netstandard#net-framework - which includes specific OS and TLS requirements (the TLS requirements can actually be softened via a feature flag that protobuf-net.Grpc surfaces via GrpcClientFactory.AllowUnencryptedHttp2). Do you meet the specified OS requirements? If not, you may have to fallback to the legacy unmanaged Channel implementation instead of GrpcChannel.ForAddress, via Grpc.Core, which would look fairly similar:
var channel = new Channel("localhost", 10042, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
//
// TODO: use exactly like before
// var calculator = channel.CreateGrpcService<ICalculator>();
// ...
//
// possible addition; try/finally with `await channel.ShutdownAsync();`
// in the finally


Thank you very much.
I just had one more issue with the "System.ServiceModel.Primitives" but installing an older version solved it.
I have one more general question. Is it also possible to call from server-side any methods from client with your framework?

@Patrick gRPC needs the client to start a connection, but: you can use a full-duplex or server-streaming method to allow the server to send messages to the client at any point, without needing to be request-response. In protobuf-net.Grpc terms, that is usually achieved by returning IAsyncEnumerable<T> (for some T) from the method, and having the client consume those messages as needed. Happy to discuss further, but there are examples etc.
